# Need explanation about demonstrative determiner

Tags: grammar, pronouns, determiners, demonstratives

Does the demonstratives refer to the next word or previously mentioned statement?

> The medieval center is Prague Castle and St. Vitus Cathedral. An evening view of **these** illuminated landmarks is one of the most memorable sights in Europe.

In the above sentence, does *these* refer to "Prague Castle and St. Vitus Cathedral" or to the "illuminated landmarks"? I'm a little confused about this. A clear explanation would be great.

Also, what's the difference between demonstrative determiners and demonstrative pronouns?

Answer (score 5):

In your example, the entire phrase *these illuminated landmarks* refers to Prague Castle and St. Vitus Cathedral. Within that phrase, the demonstrative determiner *these* tells us which illuminated landmarks the writer wants us to have in mind, that is, the landmarks just mentioned.

Demonstrative determiners are placed before nouns and, in the words of the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’, *they convey definite meaning, and specify whether the referent is near or distant in relation to the speaker.* I would add that nearness and distance need not always be taken as being in space, and that *speaker* means ‘writer’ as well. Demonstrative pronouns, like other pronouns, stand alone in place of a noun phrase that occurs elsewhere in a piece of discourse.

Answer (score 1):

A ***demonstrative*** is something like *this, that, these, those*.  When used in front of a noun, it functions as a ***demonstrative determiner***, occupying the determiner slot in a noun phrase:

- **this** old man
- **that** big red firetruck
- **these** blue hats
- **those** tired refrains

However, all four can also stand alone without a noun, in which case they become ***demonstrative pronouns***, like here:

- I didn’t want **this**.
- **That** will do.
- I was looking for **these**.
- Those are already **there**.